# Laravel Livewire multiple components not started asyncronously

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have 4 livewire components, rendered in dashboard as:

```
@livewire('profits.stats')
@livewire('costs.stats')
@livewire('leads.stats')
@livewire('sales.stats')
```

However, when page loads they run one after another instead of asyncronously. I put a sleep(3) to test, and each starts after the previous ones 3 second delay. How to get them to all start same time?

toggleShowData below has the sleep method, and sets showData=true. I saw this in a tutorial for now to have a loading for individual components

I don't think its relevant, but here is my template:

```
<div wire:init="toggleShowData">


    <div wire:loading.delay class="align-items-center">
        <div class="flex items-center justify-center ">
            <div class="w-40 h-40 border-t-4 border-b-4 border-brand-500 rounded-full animate-spin"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-auto p-4 bg-brand-300 rounded" wire:loading.remove>
        <div class="flex flex-wrap">
            <div class="relative w-full  pr-4 max-w-full flex-grow flex-1">
                <h5 class="text-gray-100 uppercase font-bold text-xs"> Costs</h5>
                <span class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-300">$34,100</span>
            </div>
            <div class="relative w-auto pl-4 flex-initial">
                <div
                    class="text-white p-3 text-center inline-flex items-center justify-center w-12 h-12 shadow-lg rounded-full  bg-red-500">
                    <i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="text-sm text-gray-100 mt-4">
            <span class="text-emerald-500 mr-2"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i> 2,99% </span>
            <span class="whitespace-nowrap"> Since last month </span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First-render is that way, yes. If you want to avoid that, you can have a look at `wire:init`.

Comment: am I using wire:init wrong? See first line in template...

Answer (score 0):

The first render of the livewire page happens inside the PHP process in the backend.

Blade sees that you are requesting a livewire component and replaces this with the result of your parse() method from your component.

This indeed happens in sync, once the page is rendered the components can render itself async

Comment: I would have understood (please correct me) the PHP process runs the render() method. Then the wire:init after rendering calls the other method. So that part I assumed would have been async. Or I am still missing something.

Comment: Currently running into the same issue. My wire:init on the child component doesn't load until the wire:init on the parent component is complete. What did you do to solve this?

Comment: If you want to do this async you should read up on using alpine, the init of alpine runs when the page is done loading